# No password for account when using SSH on server?

Tags: ssh, password

Our Server has **disabled password-based ssh login** and only works with publickey. When I add new users with **adduser**, it **prompts for a password** however and I cannot leave it empty. When I generate a random one and mail it to users, even with the notice that they don't need it, **people get confused** and write me mails that they can't login with their password.

So what is best practise here?

- set the password once, forget it and and don't tell them
- use a different command to create a user with no password at all
- continue giving them the password in case they need it for something (e.g. get sudo access later which is unlikely however)

Comment: Why would you mail the password to your users, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they have no immediate need, create the password, make it a long random string, and toss it. If they do need a password in the future, change it later on.

Comment: I marked this as correct because it seems more secure to me in case someone changes the ssh settings and permits password login.

Answer (score 3):

Use `adduser --disabled-password`.

Comment: Ah great I didn't know that option!